# Как сделать круг с размерами, указанными в свойстве size_hint в python kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Python файл:

```
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Ball(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):        
        return Ball()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Kv файл:

```
<Ball>:
    size_hint: [.1, .1] #получается не круг, а овал, т.к. ширина и длина у экрана разные
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .21}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 255, 255, 255
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

Возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы Ellipse представлял из себя круг с диаметром, длина которого зависит от ширины/длинны экрана?

Answer (score 0):

В `size_hint` нужно указать `None, None`, после этого вы сможете установить нужный размер с помощью `size`

```
<Ball>:
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 700,700
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "y": .21}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 255, 255, 255
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```